# Objective-C / iOS: Converting an array of objects to JSON string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, ipad

I am currently experimenting with the use of JSON for internet data transfer. I have been successful in receiving a JSON string and converting it into an `NSDictionary`, but have not been able to work out how to convert an array or dictionary of objects into a JSON representation.

I have read a number of posts and articles which explain how to create a `NSDictionary` of key/value pairs and then convert to JSON, which works fine for a simple array, but how do you achieve this when you have an array or dictionary of objects.

So for example, I have an array of objects "contact", which I would then like to transform into a JSON string as such:

```
"contacts":{
    "contact":[
    {
        "id":"1"
        "first_name":"john",
        "last_name":"citizen",
        "phone":"9999 9999"
    }
    {
        "id":"1"
        "first_name":"jane",
        "last_name":"doe",
        "phone":"8888 8888"
    }
    ]
 }
```

I have a `NSMutableDictionary` which is populate a list of contact objects:

```
    NSMutableDictionary* contactsToBeSynced = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    //Populate dictionary with contact objects.
    contactsToBeSynced = self.getNonSynchronisedData;
```

I then attempt to transform the dictionary of objects with the `NSJSONSerialization` method, but it fails with an error.

```
    NSError* error;
    NSString* jsonString;
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:contactsToBeSynced options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Has anyone been able to successfully do this? Would greatly appreciate some help or a point in the right direction. Cheers.

Comment: Is this for learning or do you just want to get things done? Cause there's about 5 good JSON libraries for Objective-C out there.

Answer (score 5):

About your structure - your `contactsToBeSynced` must be of `NSDictionary` class, and `contact` should be an `NSArray` containing `NSDictionary` objects for different contacts. By the way, have you tried [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)? It's serialization works better than standard `NSJSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out...

I created an `NSArray` of contact objects and using the SBJson framework with SBJsonWriter:

```
SBJsonWriter *writer = [[SBJsonWriter alloc] init];
NSString *jsonString = [writer stringWithObject:arr];
```

I got a JSON string with a list of contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer to the '' [SBJsonWriter Nested NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765037/sbjsonwriter-nested-nsdictionary/12383548#12383548) '' question. it illustrate how to properly use SBJsonWriter.

It includes **SBJsonWriter error checking!** and some pieces of advise about SBJsonWriter behaviour with NSDate, float, etc..

Excerpt:

```
NSDictionary* aNestedObject = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      @"nestedStringValue", @"aStringInNestedObject",
                                      [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"aNumberInNestedObject",
                                 nil];

NSArray * aJSonArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"arrayItem1", @"arrayItem2", @"arrayItem3", nil];

NSDictionary * jsonTestDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     @"stringValue", @"aString",
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"aNumber",
                                     [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.2345f], @"aFloat",
                                     [[NSDate date] description], @"aDate",
                                     aNestedObject, @"nestedObject",
                                     aJSonArray, @"aJSonArray",
                                     nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you write a `toDictionary` method for each class which takes the fields of interest and inserts them in a dictionary.  For numeric fields you convert to NSNumber before inserting.  If any field is an object, you call the `toDictionary` method on that object and insert the result in your dictionary.  If you have an array of objects you need to write a loop, but it's nothing exotic.

To reverse the operation you write an `initWithDictionary` method for each class.