# Convert array of image path into base64 encoded string.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64

I want to convert array of Image Paths which are in document directory into Encoded baSE 64 string.

Here is my code

```
NSArray *recipeImages = [savedImagePath valueForKey:@"Image"];
```

this array contains path of the images (MULTIPLE IMAGES).

This is how array looks in Logs.

```
 Saved Images == (
"/Users/ZAL02M/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F1F3C01E-8686-4367-82FB-80B003E2F416/data/Containers/Data/Application/694494B1-0DCA-497A-B8B0-586276EEF240/Documents/cached0.png",
"/Users/ZAL02M/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F1F3C01E-8686-4367-82FB-80B003E2F416/data/Containers/Data/Application/694494B1-0DCA-497A-B8B0-586276EEF240/Documents/cached1.png"
 )
```

How to make base64 string ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to cycle all your images and save each encoded string into a new array:

```
NSMutableArray *encodedImages = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSString *path in recipeImages)
{
    UIImage *image       = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSData *imageData    = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSString *dataString = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

    [encodedImages addObject:dataString];
}
```

Comment: Thanks - @Jacopo Penzo

Comment: How to send this array to JSON

Comment: @Ammy try something like that to have your JSON string: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20235244/2059307

Answer (score 1):

Convert your ImagePaths (Strings) to NSData and from NSData back to string via `base64EncodedStringWithOptions:`

Here the code:

```
NSArray *recipeImages = [savedImagePath valueForKey:@"Image"];
NSMutableArray *mutableBase64StringsArray = @[].mutableCopy;

for (NSString *imagePath in recipeImages)
{
    NSData *imagePathData = [imagePath dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64ImagePath = [imagePathData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    [mutableBase64StringsArray addObject:base64ImagePath];
}
```

In the `mutableBase64StringsArray` you have all imagePaths as base64 encoded strings.

Look at this post from SO for more explanations: [Base64 Decoding in iOS 7+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088231/base64-decoding-in-ios-7)

Comment: Can you give an example , As i have searched alot and not able to figure out what exactly need to do ?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

`Encoding` :

```
- (NSString *)encodeToBase64String:(UIImage *)image {
 return [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}
```

`Decoding` :

```
- (UIImage *)decodeBase64ToImage:(NSString *)strEncodeData {
  NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:strEncodeData options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
  return [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

To get `image` from your `path` you can use this code

```
NSString* imagePath = [recipeImages objectAtIndex:i];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Then add `encoded` `content` to your `array`.

Hope it helps.