# NSMutableArray to JSON object

Tags: ios, json, nsmutablearray, nsjsonserialization

I have a method where I want to return either an `NSData` object or an 'NSString' that must be a JSON object in format.

At the moment this is what I have;

```
-(NSData *)JSONData{

     NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray array];
     for (int j = 0; j < self.sales.subArray.count; j++)
     {
        SalesObject* subCategory = [self.sales.subArray objectAtIndex:j];


        NSDictionary * dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"category_id",subCategory.category_id,
                                 @"discounted",@"0",
                                 @"price",subCategory.price,
                                 @"active",subCategory.isActive, nil];
        NSLog(@"Dict %@",dict);

       [arr addObject:dict];

    }

    NSLog(@"Arr %@",arr);

   NSLog(@"Arr %@",arr);

   NSString *string = [arr description];
   NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:string options:kNilOptions error:nil];
   NSLog(@"JSON Data %@",jsonData);

   return jsonData;
}
```

As you can see I tried to convert an `NSMutableArray` to an `NSData` object but it didnt work. I get;

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary'
```

I now get the following error;

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C / iOS: Converting an array of objects to JSON string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139454/objective-c-ios-converting-an-array-of-objects-to-json-string)

Comment: what do you mean , **but it didn't work**.? That should be correct

Comment: @KumarKL I get ` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary'`

Comment: create object of array using NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Comment: What's the log of `NSLog(@"Arr %@",arr);`?

Comment: @KumarKL Thats my `NSMutableArray` its in the method at the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you have your key/value pairs reversed.  Instead use the new Objective-C dictionary literal syntax, which is shorter and easier to read, and therefore easier to spot mistakes:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{
    @"category_id" : subCategory.category_id,
    @"discounted"  : @"0",       // Should that be @(0) ???
    @"price"       : subCategory.price,
    @"active"      : subCategory.isActive
};
```

**EDIT** The additional problem relates to the use the *description of the array* (i.e. a string), rather than the array itself, being used to create the JSON data.  It should be:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr
                                                   options:kNilOptions
                                                     error:&error];
if (!jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Achtung!  Failed to create JSON data: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Good caught the mistake .

Comment: Thanks for that!! However know I get another error. I believe I am on the right track also. Please see above

Answer (score 0):

Change the dictionary definition from

```
 NSDictionary * dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"category_id",subCategory.category_id,
                             @"discounted",@"0",
                             @"price",subCategory.price,
                             @"active",subCategory.isActive, nil];
```

to

```
NSDictionary * dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             subCategory.category_id,@"category_id",
                             @"0", @"discounted",
                             subCategory.price,@"price",
                             subCategory.isActive, @"active", nil];
```